# Magento 2 Customer Login Notification Email Sent to Customer

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How to Magento 2 Customer Login Notification Email Sent to Customer whenever they login they will get Notification via email

Comment: I have added answer for you. Please check and let me know if you have any query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send notification with the use of observer. You need to have email template id , sender information and receiver information.

Please follow below steps.

> Step 1: Please create events.xml file under path
> PackageName/Vendor/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_observer" instance="PackageName\Vendor\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Please create CustomerLogin.php file under path
> PackageName/Vendor/Observer/

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Vendor\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Area;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder
     */
    private $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        $this->sendEmail($customer);
    }

    public function sendEmail($customer)
    {
        $senderInfo = [
            'name' => $customer->getName(),
            'email' => $customer->getEmail(),
        ];

        $recieverEmail = 'test@zealousweb.com';
        $emailTemplateId = 2;// Here change template id or if you have configuration for email template then pass here

        $emailTemplateVariables = [];
        $emailTempVariables['name'] = $customer->getName();

        $postObject = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        $postObject->setData($emailTempVariables);
        
        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($emailTemplateId)
                    ->setTemplateOptions(
                        [
                            'area' => Area::AREA_FRONTEND,
                            'store' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
                        ]
                    )
                    ->setTemplateVars(['data' => $postObject])
                    ->setFrom($senderInfo)
                    ->addTo($recieverEmail)
                    ->setReplyTo($recieverEmail)
                    ->getTransport();
        $transport->sendMessage();
    }
}
```

**I have created email template from admin and passed that email template id. Please change and set email template as per your need.**

Email Template Content:- https://prnt.sc/10gzmza

```
{{template config_path="design/email/header_template"}}

<p class="greeting">Dear {{var data.name}},</p>

Please set content according to your need.

{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}
```

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: its working thanks

Comment: Can you please approve and upvote this?